# How to handle HTML form submission

Tags: html, forms, email, redirect, submit

Thanks in advance for the help. I know this is probably a simple question, as I am relatively new to HTML.

I have a form on my site for people to become members.. I want users to input their information and click submit. When they do that, I want an email to be sent to me. However, I want the user to be redirected to a different page on the site where they will pay for their membership. How can I do both of those things (send email, redirect) at the same time?

Here is my form:

```
<form>
    First name:     <input type="text" name="firstname">
    Last name:      <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
    Street:         <input type="text" name="street" size="60"><br>
    City:           <input type="text" name="city">
    State:          <input type="text" name="state"> 
    ZIP:            <input type="text" name="zip"><br>
    Email:          <input type="text" name="email" size="60"><br>
    Phone:          <input type="text" name="phone" size="60"><br>
    City/Township:  <input type="text" name="votingcity">
    Precinct No.:   <input type="text" name="precinct"><br>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <p>Government regulations require the following information:<br></p><br>
    Occupation:         <input type="text" name="occupation" size="60"><br>
    Employer's Name:    <input type="text" name="employer" size="60"><br>
    Employer's Street:  <input type="text" name="emp_street" size="60"><br>
    Employer's City:    <input type="text" name="emp_city">
    Employer's State:   <input type="text" name="emp_state">
    Employer's ZIP:     <input type="text" name="emp_zip"><br>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    Submit <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: you  have to  use  the any of language like php    to send email or redirect

Answer (score 1):

Try this at your opening statement it can be done in html it's not pretty but it might work for you

```
<form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to have a look of PHP tutorials (cf: [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php)). The following code will redirect you to an "action.php" page where you will can execute php code (send email, redirect to another, etc.)

**index.html**

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>Your age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

**Action.php**

```
<?php
$message = "your message";

// Send mail
mail('abc@something.com', 'Your Subject', $message);

header('Location: payment.php');  
?>
```

**UPDATE:**
In your PHP page you can also manage your form data. For example you can access the user first name with this `$_POST['firstname']`. Or display user informations in you payement page  like this:

```
Hi M. <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['lastname']); ?>.
```

I don't know what you want to do with the form data, but you can send them in the email or store them in a database.

You can also use other language than PHP such as Java, VB.net, etc. But in my opinion, PHP will probably be easier to learn.

Comment: Your Javascript code doesn't launch an email; it only sends the user to the follow-up page.

Comment: And your PHP does nothing with the form data

Comment: You are right, the javascript don't really send an email, it opens your default email client and pre-populate content.
Otherwise, I update my answer to add more detail about php dealing with form.

Comment: I tried your HTML and Javascript and it didn't open my email client.

Comment: Btw you have 'payement' instead of 'payment'

Comment: It works fine for me, it is just an html mailto. Did this link works for you: `<a href="mailto:abc@something.com">send an email</a>` ?

Comment: Yes a mailto works fine for me. I don't see why what you're doing ought to work; once you change the page (be it via an email link or a new url) the javascript should stop running. Also document.location.href is supposed to be used as read-only, and window.location.href is preferred when using Javascript to redirect to a page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a server side page for form action to send email and display membership page. When users submit form, they will be directed to this page.

`<form method="post" action="link to subscription page. Eg: payment.php">
</form>`

In payment.php, display payment form and write an function to send email.

```
<?php
//Write send email function here
?>
<html>
<!-- Display payment form here -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using just HTML, you will need to know a server side scripting language such as PHP or ASP.

Answer (score 0):

How are you processing payments? If I were doing this for myself I would probably have the form data sent to the payment processor (e.g. PayPal) and included in the invoice. I would imagine most payment processors have an option to notify you via email when a payment is received.

But you didn't ask how *I* would do it, you asked how you can submit a form such that an email is sent and the browser is redirected to another page.

If you can't use my solution I really think you're best off with throwing PHP into the mix.

***signup.html***

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
Street: <input type="text" name="street" size="60"><br>
City: <input type="text" name="city">
State: <input type="text" name="state"> 
ZIP: <input type="text" name="zip"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="60"><br>
Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" size="60"><br>
City/Township: <input type="text" name="votingcity">
Precinct No.: <input type="text" name="precinct"><br>
<br><hr><br>
<p>Government regulations require the following information:<br></p><br>
Occupation: <input type="text" name="occupation" size="60"><br>
Employer's Name: <input type="text" name="employer" size="60"><br>
Employer's Street: <input type="text" name="emp_street" size="60"><br>
Employer's City: <input type="text" name="emp_city">
Employer's State: <input type="text" name="emp_state">
Employer's ZIP: <input type="text" name="emp_zip"><br>
<br><hr><br>
Submit <input type="submit">
</form>
```

***process.php***

```
<?php
  $message = '';
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $message .= "$key => $value\n";
  }
  mail('youraddress@whatever.com','New User Registration',$message);
  header('Location: payment.html');
?>
```

Make sure that `<?php` is the very beginning of process.php; no preceding text or whitespace of any kind.

The email you'll receive will look something like this:

```
firstname => Homer
lastname => Simpson
street => 724 Evergreen Terrace
city => Springfield
state => Unknown
zip => ?????
email => hsimpson@compuserve.net
phone => (939) 555-0113
votingcity => Springfield
precinct => N/A
occupation => Nuclear Safety Inspector
employer => C. Montgomery Burns
emp_street => 100 Industrial Way
emp_city => Springfield
emp_state => Unknown
emp_zip => ?????
```

Answer (score 0):

All actions will be taken at server side. so you have to use any server side language. in your case php would be suitable. you can send data from html form after validating all fields. You can send it with ajax or traditional way and if you receive response as ok then you can move to next page.

With jQuery forminteract you can add validation tags in your HTML inputs as i have used below in firstNamelike this.

```
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" data-validation-notNull data-validation-notNull-message="Please enter first Name">
<span data-error="firstName"></span>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
    Street: <input type="text" name="street" size="60"><br>
    City: <input type="text" name="city">
    State: <input type="text" name="state"> 
    ZIP: <input type="text" name="zip"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="60"><br>
    Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" size="60"><br>
    City/Township: <input type="text" name="votingcity">
    Precinct No.: <input type="text" name="precinct"><br>
    <br><hr><br>
    <p>Government regulations require the following information:<br></p><br>
    Occupation: <input type="text" name="occupation" size="60"><br>
    Employer's Name: <input type="text" name="employer" size="60"><br>
    Employer's Street: <input type="text" name="emp_street" size="60"><br>
    Employer's City: <input type="text" name="emp_city">
    Employer's State: <input type="text" name="emp_state">
    Employer's ZIP: <input type="text" name="emp_zip"><br>
    <br><hr><br>
<button type="button" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

javascript at bottom of page would be.

```
var form=$("form").find("[name]").formInteract();
$("#btn-submit").click(function(){
    if(!form.validate()){
      //return if form is not valid
      return;
     }

form.postAjax("url", function(rsp){
 //do your stuff with response.

 });

});
```

Here is the linke to forminteract project
https://bitbucket.org/ranjeet1985/forminteract

Comment: You should probably mention that this is your own personal plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use form-endpoint services like formspree.io or formcarry.com they provide email notifications and user redirection after the submit, if you want to use their data later, you can use Formcarry's Zapier integration for Mysql or MongoDB to save the data to the database, or you can set up a webhook to your PHP file, and save processed data.